# 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' nodeJS Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Unable to execute this. When I execute the queries separately I am not getting any errors.

```
   app.post('/Fu',function(req,res,next){

    var username = req.body.uname;
    var pass = req.body.pwd;

     con.query(' SELECT name FROM fun WHERE name = "' +username+'" ; SELECT password FROM fun WHERE password = "' +pass+'" ',function(err, results,fields) {



       if (results.length > 0) {

           var w = results[0].password;

           var q = results[1].name;
           //console.log(q);
           console.log('Login was successful');
           } 

         else {
                console.log('Login was not successful');
            }

     });

     res.send("success1");

    });
```

Can someone help with me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add a check for the error. It will give you more information. If an error is returned, results will likely be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to change your:

```
 con.query(' SELECT name FROM fun WHERE name = "' +username+'" ; SELECT password FROM fun WHERE password = "' +pass+'" ',function(err, results,fields) {
```

to:

```
 con.query(' SELECT name, password FROM fun WHERE name = "' +username+'" AND password = "' +pass+'" ',function(err, results,fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
```